# On the Cantor set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I found on the wikipedia page

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set

what the Cantor set $\mathcal{C}$ can be written as 
$$\mathcal{C}=[0,1]\setminus \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{i=0}^{3^{j-1}-1} (\frac{3i+1}{3^j}, \frac{3i+2}{3^j}) $$

Is this correct? If yes, does anyone have idea how to demonstrate or where can I find proof?

Comment: This is a definition of the Cantor set, not a result that needs to be proved. Do you have a different definition that you'd like to prove is equivalent to this one?

Comment: It is pretty much the definition.

Comment: @CliveNewstead http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set#Historical_remarks

Comment: @studiosus http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set#Historical_remarks

Comment: @ABC: OK, add "ternary" to what I wrote.

Comment: @ABC: First of all, not an answer but a comment. Secondly, it all depends on what you mean by the "Cantor set". The most common definition I know is the one commonly known as "ternary Cantor set". An alternative one is of "discontinuum", which is any perfect Hausdorff compact totally disconnected and nonempty. It is indeed a nontrivial theorem that the latter is always homeomorphic to the former. Whoever write the wiki article did not make it clear and the is OP's responsibility to clarify what exactly she/he wants to know.

Comment: @studiosus think the emphasis is on demonstrate/derive the relation from the OP. As to be fair that's a lot of intervals, and it can be confusing to see straight off the bat whats being removed. Like the fact that you're removing subsets of removed intervals again and again with that definition.

Comment: Forgot to add "2nd countable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't something you prove... this is the definition of the Cantor set.

Answer (score 1):

So we're looking at the cantor ternary set on $[0,1]$. The idea is to divide the interval in the j'th step into 3^j equal pieces. At each step you remove the "middle third" so to speak, of what remains in the last step, of each of the segments.

So the open intervals are being removed from $[0,1]$ and the bold is the ones removed in each step. I've done two steps below.

So step 1

$[0,\frac{1}{3}], \quad$ $\boldsymbol{(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3})}$, $\quad [\frac{1}{3},1]$,

remove open interval

step 2

$\overbrace{[\frac{0}{9},\frac{1}{9}], \:\boldsymbol{(\frac{1}{9},\frac{2}{9})}, \:[\frac{2}{9},\frac{3}{9}]}, \;\overbrace{(\frac{3}{9},\frac{4}{9}), \:\boldsymbol{(\frac{4}{9},\frac{5}{9})}, \:(\frac{5}{9},\frac{6}{9})}, \;\overbrace{[\frac{6}{9},\frac{7}{9}],\: \boldsymbol{(\frac{7}{9},\frac{8}{9})},\: [\frac{8}{9},\frac{9}{9}]}$

remove open intervals

For each subsection and by that I mean blocks of three (overbraces), note that the numerator of the leftmost fractions go 0,1,2 mod 3 and it's always the 1 mod three removed (hence middle third in some sense), eg $\boldsymbol{(\frac{4}{9},\frac{5}{9})}$, $4 \equiv 1\pmod{3}$. So you remove $\large(\frac{3k+1}{3^j},\frac{3k+2}{3^j})$ on the j'th step and run k from $0$ to $3^{j-1}$ (as $3*3^{j-1}=3^j$). Then you've to union over all $j \in \mathbb{N}$ and remove the full union from [0,1].

You'll note that in the definition of that union we're overdoing it a lot, eg we've removed that middle interval in step one but we include a third of it again in step two. Since it's a union it doesn't matter though, and the definition is easier this way I think.

Hope that's kind of clear, I'm a bit tired :)